# running web based project using IP address virtual host returning error

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am running my web based application in windows server I wanted to create a virtual so that people will access some address and not using IP. My reason is that when I used IP address this is what happening.

[image]

There are words in URL saying `Note secure` I want it to look like.

[image]

Where it is saying secure.

When I try to access the virtual host(`myproject.dev` in the url) I get.

> This site can’t be reached
>   This site on the company, organization or school intranet has the same URL as an external website.

My hosts file contains:

```
192.168.7.12         myproject.dev
127.0.0.1            myproject.dev
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAlias www.myproject.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

My httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

UPDATE:

in the url I notice when I access only `myproject.dev` the url changes to `https://myproject.dev/` it add `https://` maybe this the reason?

Comment: That's called an `SSL Certificate`.

Comment: how should I work on that? @crimson589